# Android Firebase: How do I record the rating value in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have made a feedback app with 5 `imageViews` each containing a rating from 1-5 (using `setTag`).
The user clicks on one of the `imageViews` and the app sends the rating value (using `getTag`) to Firebase realtime database.
Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    ImageView oneStar, twoStar, threeStar, fourStar, fiveStar;
    Intent intent;
    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    public void displayScore() {
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Score.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        name =  findViewById(R.id.editTextPersonName);
        oneStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        twoStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        threeStar = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        fourStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        fiveStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        oneStar.setTag(1);
        twoStar.setTag(2);
        threeStar.setTag(3);
        fourStar.setTag(4);
        fiveStar.setTag(5);

        class OnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, view.getTag().toString());
                if (name.length() == 0){
                    name.setError("Please enter your full name.");
                }
                else {
                    name.setError(null);
                    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");
                    //Fetch all values
                    String username = name.getText().toString();
                    String value = view.getTag().toString();
                    int rating = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    UserHelper helper = new UserHelper(username,rating);
                    reference.push().setValue(helper);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Feedback submitted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
                }
            }
        }
        oneStar.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener ());
        twoStar.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener ());
        threeStar.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener ());
        fourStar.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener ());
        fiveStar.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener ());
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I send the tag value (rating) to firebase analytics since I want to display the average rating on a data studio dashboard. I am using the `SELECT_CONTENT` Event and `CONTENT_TYPE` Param
in the code above but nothing is being populated in Firebase analytics.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long did you wait for the event to show up? See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html

Comment: I don't think the event is logging on at all. Been waiting for a couple of hours now.